¿Por qué al comparar dos String con el mismo texto, en java, siempre devuelve falso?
Al comparar dos String con el mismo texto, en java, siempre devuelve falso, por qué si el valor es igual?
public class _Q1 {
    static String str1 = "Java";
    static String str2 = new String("java");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Is: "+(str1 == str2? true: false));
        System.out.println("Is: "+(str2.toString().equals(str1)? true: false));
    }

}


El operador "==" compara dos referencias, es decir, devuelve true si ambos objetos ocupan la misma posición de memoria.El método "equals" compara los valores de los objetos ..vos estas  comparando Java (J mayuscula) con java (j minuscula) por eso te devuelve false ,tendrias que usar equalsIgnoreCase

Para comparar el contenido de objetos String debes usar alguno de los métodos equals. Y, los ternarios son redundantes, porque ya el método en sí mismo devuelve lo que deba ser, true o false. Del mismo modo, aplicar .toString() a un objeto del tipo String también es redundante. Es como decirle: sé lo que ya eres. Como ya comenta @Dramaturgo, para una comparación donde no se tome en cuenta mayúsculas/minúsculas, puedes usar equalsIgnoreCase. Con esto bastaría: System.out.println("Is: "+str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2));

Para completar las excelentes respuestas de Dramaturgo y Cedano, dada la forma particular que tiene Java de crear cadenas a partir de literales (antes de crear un nuevo objeto, verifica si hay otro igual, y en ese caso, asigna la referencia al objeto existente) en ese exclusivo caso (cadenas creadas a partir de literales) es correcto compararlas con ==.
